# Multiple methods named 'tag' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing the error "Multiple methods named 'tag' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes" since trying to update an old piece of code for 64-bit, the code is;

```
- (IBAction)undoClick:(id)sender
{
    [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] playSoundEffect:0];

    for(UIView *view in [self.bigView subviews])
    {
        if(view.tag == lastTag)
            [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if([[extraList lastObject] tag] == lastTag) // Here is error
        [extraList removeLastObject];

    if(lastTag > 1)
        lastTag--;
}
```

The problematic line is marked,  but here also FYI

```
if([[extraList lastObject] tag] == lastTag)
```

Comment: what kind of data in extraList @Hypergater

Comment: Hi, it is `extraList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: what kind of data you store in it like label ,uibutton etc... as you use tag so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the `extraList` is a regular `NSArray` and then the `lastObject` is of type `id`. If your `extraList` contains only instances of `UIView` try to change the declaration of `extraList` from `NSArray *extraList` to `NSArray<UIView *> *extraList` and this should resolve your issue.

This is the part of modernized Objective-C API that allow generics (to the limited scope but still).

Comment: Hi, it is `extraList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: Thanks, but what is the declaration of your extraList? Is it a @property or local variable? Try to change the type to `NSMutableArray <UIView *> * `

Comment: Hi, it is a variable `NSMutableArray *extraList;`

Comment: So try to change it according to my previous comment

Comment: I have changed it from  `NSMutableArray *extraList;`   to `NSMutableArray <UIView *> *extraList;`

The error has cleared, I will check the code functions correctly but it looks good so far!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

**I guess lastTag is your integer value compare as this**

```
if( [extraList lastObject]integerValue] == lastTag)
 {
     // logic here
 }
```

**If last tag is String than simple use this**

```
if( [[extraList lastObject]isEqualToString: lastTag])
 {
     // logic here
 }
```